# Ordering of the bibliography with biblatex, notes at the end

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I do have a problem with the order in the whole reference section. I use the packages below and implemented hyperlinks to each reference in the bibliography. This is done (as shown below) by making notes. However, I have the problem that the notes are not shown at the end but before the pages, like in the example below. How can I tell LaTeX that the notes should be at the end of each reference?

`.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear-ibid,citestyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\bibliography{mybibliography_url}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`.bib` file

```
@article{blanchard1989The,
  title={The Dynamic Effects of Aggregate Demand and Supply Disturbances},
  author={Blanchard, Olivier and Quah, Danny},
  journal={American Economic Review},
  pages={655-73},
  year={1989},
  publisher={American Economic Association},
  note={\href{https://catalogue.polytechnique.fr/site.php?id=334&fileid=2378}{View online}}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `biber` as backend one can write a `SourceMap` to move the content of `note` to `addendum`.  Here is a solution to do the same for other backends.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \savefield{note}{\myadd}%
  \clearfield{note}%
  \newbibmacro{finentry}{
    \restorefield{note}{\myadd}\printfield{note}
    \finentry}%
}
```

The idea is to use `\savefield` to store the content of `note` in a temporary macro, use `\clearfield` to suppress to print the note, and restore the content saved in the temporary macro at the end using the `finentry` bib macro hook (which is executed at the end of the various drivers printing a bib entry).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `biblatex`, in principle one may use the `addendum` instead of the `note` field in order to place notes at the very end of a bibliography entry. `addendum` is also useful for a "hidden" URL like in your example. If one wants to provide a non-hidden URL, one should use the `url` (and possibly the `urldate`) field.